# Recarregar imagem no Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Criei um plugin para cortar imagens através de javascript e PHP mas estou a ter dificuldades em revelar a imagem editada após o sucesso do crop em `ajax`.
Já pesquisei sobre o assunto e encontrei um truque que funciona para a maioria dos browsers principais menos o Chrome que consiste em gerar uma string aleatória e juntá-la no final do link da imagem.
Este é o código que estou a usar de momento:

```
$.post('printmw/ajax_crop', $.param(croper), function(result){
    data = JSON.parse(result);
    if(data.result == 'success'){

        $(active_img).parent().find('img').attr('src', 'images/'+croper['image']+'#'+ new Date().getTime());

    }
});
```

Como faço para o Chrome libertar a imagem em cache e recarregar com a nova?

Comment: Geralmente, funciona normalmente comigo quando coloco as strings na frente (mesmo no Google Chrome). Tente, ao invés de usar `#`, usar um `?`. Algo que retorne tipo `minha_image.png?78782012124`

Answer (score 2):

Exclua a tag img e add ela de novo com as modificações.

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes e/ou exemplos? Para melhorar a resposta e ela não parecer tão *seca*.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post('printmw/ajax_crop', $.param(croper), function(result){
    data = JSON.parse(result);
    if(data.result == 'success'){

       $(active_img).parent().find('img').attr('src', 'images/'+croper['image']+'?t='+ new Date().getTime());

    }
});
```

Comment: Poderia explicar os motivos da alterações e detalhar melhor a sua resposta?